# How to return View() to another action without losing data of @Html.DropDownListFor()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In the View, I designed a @Html.DropDownListFor() and put the source in `public ActionResult Index(){...}`. It's working without a problem.

Now, I want to reference to `Index()` by another action. Like this:

```
public ActionResult AnotherAction()
{
   // do something...
   return View("index");
}
```

When I run `AnotherAction()`, all data of DropDownListFor() will be lost.

I mean that: When I render to `Index.cshtml` (at line `return View("index");`), the code in action `Index()` won't execute. So the data source will be lost.

But, if I change that line to `return RedirectToAction("index", "default");`. That's okay.

Here is my problem: in the action `AnotherAction()`, I want to store some values into ViewBag and display it in View. But all values of ViewBag will be lost when I make a redirect.

I want to use `return View("index")`, not make a new redirect.

And my question is: How to keep the data of DropDownList (in action `Index()`) and the values of ViewBag (in action `AnotherAction()`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate the code to build your DDL and call it from both actions.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //do index action related stuff
   BuildDataForDDL();
   return View("index");
}

public ActionResult AnotherAction(YourModel yourModel)
{
    //do another action related stuff
   BuildDataForDDL();
   ViewBag.Add(SelectedValue, yourModel.DropDownSelectedValue);
   return View("index");
}

private void BuildDataForDDL()
{
   // build ddl
   //ViewBag.Add(etc,etc);
}
```

> When I run AnotherAction(), all data of DropDownListFor() will be lost.
>
> But all values of ViewBag will be lost when I make a redirect.

Don't think of it as a redirect, nor, the data being lost.

The request to YourController/AnotherAction is another request that the routing engine sends to that action, this is a completely separate request to the Index call, it doesn't share the state of the ViewBag between those requests.

Since it's a new request, the ViewBag is empty, so you need to run all the code you need to build what you want for whatever result you return; in this case building the DDL data and putting it into the ViewBag.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't think it's the best way. Because if you re-compile the method `BuildDataForDDL()`, it won't `remember` the selected value. I mean that: you have 3 values, `1 2 3`. And you select 2, you get it to do something. That's okay. But when you `return View("index")`, it will display the current selected value is `1` on the page

Comment: Then you have to post the selected value to AnotherAction. The change to DDL is on the client and the actions are being run on the server. You need to send the data back so the action can use it.

Comment: I've put an example in the answer. MVC is built on HTTP which is stateless. Have you come from an aspx background? The aspx viewstate handles the changes to the state between the first load and postbacks, to keep states and hides the client/server distinction. MVC doesn't hide it, so you have to be explicit in what you're sending back.

Comment: oh. yes. I have come from webform. I will try it with your advice. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. Once you've got it working, useful parts of the framework to get familiar with that's doing stuff "under the hood", is the ModelBinder (which will take the data in the GET querystring or POST form and populate the parameters to an Action) and the Routing engine (which will look at the URL and decide which Action to execute).